# How to output a list of procedures in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

In a schema i've created a couple of procedures for some tables.
I want to know if there's a way to display of all the procedures. I can have a description of a table with `desc [tablename]` is there something similar that displays all the procedures created ?

Comment: select * from all_source where type = 'PROCEDURE';

Comment: what should i use instead of `all_source` to have it only for the current connection/user . That output displays them but they are together with thousands of other procedures mostly from `SYS`.

Comment: use another filter in where clause for owner = 'your schema name'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
select * from user_objects
where object_type = 'PROCEDURE';
```

It will display procedures created in your own schema (actually, the one you're currently connected to).

use

```
select * from all_objects
where object_type = 'PROCEDURE';
```

to show all procedures you have access to.

Remember that there are other object types also such as FUNCTION and PACKAGE